# Can't create tables in MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-workbench

I've just installed MySQL workbench on my computer and have importend an old database into the system which seems to be working find.  All the data is there and tables.  I can do select, insert, updates etc.

However, if I expand a database, I see tables, views, routines.  If I then right click on tables, nothing happens if I click create table...  However, if I manually type in the create sql command, it creates a table just fine.

The old laptop has:

```
OS: Ubuntu 10.04.3
MySQL: 5.1.41
MySQL Workbench: 5.2.33
```

The new laptop has:

```
OS: Ubuntu 10.04.3
MySQL: 5.1.41
MySQL Workbench: 5.2.37
```

I have also tried starting mysql workbench using `sudo mysql-workbench` and I get the same problem.

However, it does give the following output at command line if I start it from the command line on the new laptop:

```
oshirowanen@laptop:~$ mysql-workbench
Ready.

** Message: query.save_edits built-in command is being overwritten
** Message: query.discard_edits built-in command is being overwritten

** (mysql-workbench-bin:2737): CRITICAL **: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1' failed

(mysql-workbench-bin:2737): glibmm-CRITICAL **: 
unhandled exception (type Glib::Error) in signal handler:
domain: gtk-builder-error-quark
code  : 6
what  : Unknown internal child: selection


(mysql-workbench-bin:2737): glibmm-CRITICAL **: 
unhandled exception (type Glib::Error) in signal handler:
domain: gtk-builder-error-quark
code  : 6
what  : Unknown internal child: selection

oshirowanen@laptop:~$
```

On the old laptop I get:

```
oshirowanen@laptop:~$ mysql-workbench
Log levels '0111000'
disabling log level 0
enabling log level 1
enabling log level 2
enabling log level 3
disabling log level 4
disabling log level 5
disabling log level 6
Ready.
```

Any idea why I can't create tables using the mouse?

Comment: Could it possibly be a privileges issue? Are you running as root, or some other user?

Comment: Please see updated question.  I started mysql-workbench from the command line on both the old laptop and new, and look at the difference at the terminal.

Comment: cross post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/104230/cant-create-tables-with-mysql-workbench

Comment: and another one: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31686/difference-in-command-line-output-when-starting-mysql-workbench

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a known issue with Ubuntu 10.04:

go to:
/usr/share/mysql-workbench/modules/data/editor_mysql_table_live.glade 
and delete all the nodes that look like this:

```
<child internal-child="selection">
    <object class="GtkTreeSelection" id="treeview-selection5"/>
</child>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Any idea what that happened on my new laptop and not on my old laptop?  The only difference I know is that on the old laptop, I installed Ubuntu using the Ubuntu 10.04 and eventually upgraded to 10.04.1, then 2, then 3 via `sudo aptitude full-upgrade`.   On the new laptop, I downloaded the latest image of Ubuntu which was Ubuntu 10.04.3.